# GV$PERSISTENT_QUEUES Fields

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, queue, advanced-queuing

I am wondering what the fields on the oracle table `GV$PERSISTENT_QUEUES` really mean.

The Documentation:

```
ENQUEUED_MSGS           NUMBER  Number of messages enqueued
DEQUEUED_MSGS           NUMBER  Number of messages dequeued
  Note: This column will not be incremented until all the subscribers of the message have dequeued the message and its retention time has elapsed.
...
ENQUEUED_EXPIRY_MSGS    NUMBER  Number of messages enqueued with expiry
ENQUEUED_DELAY_MSGS     NUMBER  Number of messages enqueued with delay
MSGS_MADE_EXPIRED       NUMBER  Number of messages expired by time manager
MSGS_MADE_READY         NUMBER  Number of messages made ready by time manager
...
ENQUEUE_TRANSACTIONS    NUMBER  Number of enqueue transactions
DEQUEUE_TRANSACTIONS    NUMBER  Number of dequeue transactions
```

[Oracle Documentation (11.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_2092.htm#REFRN30460)

My Questions:

- How can the number of dequeued messages be larger than the number of enqueued messages?
- If messages with a certain delay get added to the queue, do they get counted at `ENQUEUED_MSGS` and `ENQUEUED_DELAY_MSGS`?
- If a message with a certain delay gets delivered after the delay, will it get counted at `DEQUEUED_MSGS` and `MSGS_MADE_READY`?

  - If so, how can `MSGS_MADE_READY` be larger than `ENQUEUED_DELAY_MSGS`?
- What do the fields `ENQUEUED_EXPIRY_MSGS` and `MSGS_MADE_EXPIRED` mean?
- What's the difference between `ENQUEUED_MSGS` and `ENQUEUE_TRANSACTIONS`, same with dequeueing?

Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure of having found the solution to most of the above questions.

- `DEQUEUED_MSGS` can be greater than `ENQUEUED_MSGS` in case of reboot of a database. Queue Entries that are still in the Queue Table will remain there. After database reboot, the entries will get dequeued and added to the number of dequeued messages, but they won't get added to the number of enqueued messages.
- The Field `ENQUEUED_MSGS` is the sum of all messages that got enqueued into the Queue.
- The Field `ENQUEUED_DELAY_MSGS` is the sum of all messages enqueued with delay.
- `ENQUEUED_MSGS - ENQUEUED_DELAY_MSGS` = All messages that got enqueued without delay
- The same is for `DEQUEUED_MSGS` (all) and `MSGS_MADE_READY` (only with delay).

I don't know yet what `ENQUEUE_TRANSACTIONS` and `DEQUEUE_TRANSACTIONS` mean (maybe  `DEQUEUE_TRANSATIONS` describes the number of dequeues of one message in a multi consumer queue), but I won't use those fields.